# how to allow access to method to only be passed as a delegate but not executed?

Tags: c#, .net-core, delegates

I have a private method I would like to allow access to only to be passed as a delegate but not be executed otherwise.

for example:

```
class a
{
   public delegate int myDelegate(int a);
   public static int myMethod(int data, myDelegate action)
   {
        //my code
   }

   private static int methodA(int a){ //code}
   private static int methodb(int a){ //code}
}

class b
{
   public void anotherMethod()
   {
       var doAction = new myDelegate(methodA);
       result = myMethod(8, doAction);
   }
}
```

so in my example I would like methodA and MethodB to only be executed from within class a, but still enabling access to them so they can be used as delegates to be passed to methods from class a.

is it at all possible?
currently I am getting an error "methodA is inaccessible due to protection level"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are saying is not possible. Once a class has an instance of a delegate, no one can stop it from calling it. So if class `B` were able to pass a delegate to `myMethod`, it would also be able to call that delegate directly, unless `methodA` and `methodB` need special parameters, that only `A` knows about, to do anything useful.

One way of doing something similar is to create an enum called something like `MethodOfA` and declare `MethodA` and `MethodB` as the possible values of the enum. In class `A` declare a private `Dictionary<MethodOfA, MyDelegate> methodDict` that records what each enum value correspond to. Then declare another overload of `myMethod` that takes a `MethodOfA` like this:

```
public static int myMethod(int data, MethodOfA action) 
    => myMethod(data, methodDict[action]);
```

Nevertheless, this looks like bad design to me. Maybe you don't need the overload of `myMethod(int, MyDelegate)` in the first place, and just check the enum to perform the corresponding action. The other thing that you might try is the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you'd like to know how to use delegates (pass actions / functions) as parameters?

If so, then you should use Action<> and/or Func<> as they're delegates. Your code could look like this then:

```
    class a
    {
        public int myMethod(int data, Func<int, int> func)
        {
            return func.Invoke(data);
        }
    }

    class b
    {
        public void anotherMethod()
        {
            var classA = new a();
            var result = classA.myMethod(8, Double);
        }

        private int Double(int i)
        {
            return i * 2;
        }
    }
```